# How to setup Kestrel to handle SSL with in K8

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kestrel-http-server

We have an ASP.Net Core 6.0 application running on a Kestrel Server. Moreover, we have an Ingress controller in front of the application. Please find the below diagram showcasing the architecture of the current solution (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

[image]

We were able to configure the SSL certificate on the Ingress controller. However, when we wanted to add the same on to the Kestrel server, we came across the below issue.

> [11:09:58 WRN] Storing keys in a directory
> '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside
> of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is
> destroyed. [11:09:58 INF] User profile is available. Using
> '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not
> be encrypted at rest. Setting up Kestrel Server Adding address:
> 0.0.0.0 Loading Certificate... Loading Certificate... done. [11:10:00 INF] Creating key {14654ccb-769b-4cab-b418-c22144413067} with creation
> date 2022-03-14 11:10:00Z, activation date 2022-03-14 11:10:00Z, and
> expiration date 2022-06-12 11:10:00Z. [11:10:00 WRN] No XML encryptor
> configured. Key {14654ccb-769b-4cab-b418-c22144413067} may be
> persisted to storage in unencrypted form. [11:10:00 INF] Writing data
> to file
> '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/key-14654ccb-769b-4cab-b418-c22144413067.xml'.
> [11:10:02 WRN] Overriding address(es) 'http://+:80'. Binding to
> endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
> Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address
> https://[::]:443: address already in use.
> ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
> error, String callerName) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint
> endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint
> endpoint) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
> endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
> endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
> endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1
> listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
> host) at SystemSettings.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /src/SystemSettings.API/Program.cs:line 19

**Porgam.cs**

```
public static void ConfigureEndpoints(this KestrelServerOptions options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up Kestrel Server");
            var configuration = options.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var environment = options.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

            var endpoints = configuration.GetSection("KestrelServer:Endpoints")
                .GetChildren()
                .ToDictionary(section => section.Key, section =>
                {
                    var endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration();
                    section.Bind(endpoint);
                    return endpoint;
                });

            foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
            {
                var ipAddresses = new List<IPAddress>();

                var config = endpoint.Value;
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(config.Host, out var ipAddress))
                {
                    ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
                }

                foreach (var address in ipAddresses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Adding address: {address}");

                    if (config.Scheme == "https")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Loading Certificate...");

                        var certificate = LoadCertificate(config.Certificate);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Loading Certificate... done.");

                        Console.WriteLine($"Executing port listen on- Address: {address} and Port: {config.Port.Value}");

                        options.Listen(address, config.Port.Value, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                        });

                        Console.WriteLine($"Executing port listening completed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, config.Port.Value, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

================================================================================

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(IConfiguration configuration, string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.PreventHostingStartupKey, "true")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseSerilog(SeriLogger.Configure)
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .UseKestrel(options =>
                      {
                          KestrelServerOptionsExtensions.ConfigureEndpoints(options);
                      });
           });
```

================================================================================

**App settings Json**

```
 "KestrelServer": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Host": "<Private server IP>",
        "Port": 80,
        "Scheme": "http"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Host": "<Private server IP>",
        "Port": 443,
        "Scheme": "https",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
          "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://[::]:443: address already in use.` I think you need check the port.